# Allow only azure services to call azure logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-logic-apps, azure-automation, azure-eventgrid

Is there any way that I can configure an azure Logic App to only allow Azure IP addresses? My Logic App is called by a few different services, Event Grid and Runbooks.

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways to secure a Logic App.

[Secure access to your logic apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app)

> There are many tools available to help you secure your logic app.
>
> - Securing access to trigger a logic app (HTTP Request Trigger)
> - Securing access to manage, edit, or read a logic app
> - Securing access to contents of inputs and outputs for a run
> - Securing parameters or inputs within actions in a workflow
> - Securing access to services that receive requests from a workflow

Specifically I think you want to look at [Restrict incoming IP addresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app#restrict-incoming-ip-addresses).

> In addition to the Shared Access Signature, you may wish to restrict
>   calling a logic app only from specific clients. For example, if you
>   manage your endpoint through Azure API Management, you can restrict
>   the logic app to only accept the request when the request comes from
>   the API Management instance IP address.
>
> This setting can be configured within the logic app settings:
>
> 1. In the Azure portal, open the logic app you want to add IP address restrictions
> 2. Click the Access control configuration menu item under Settings
> 3. Specify the list of IP address ranges to be accepted by the trigger

I suppose the difficulty you might have is knowing which IPs to restrict, but you might be able to achieve a similiar affect using a different mechanism.